# WCF design - One Request and Response object or multiple?

Tags: wcf, architecture, request, response

Should you make one request/response object for each method or should you have one per service?

My service request object would only have 5 different things in it if I used it across all methods as I use the same inputs for almost all methods.

The response object would only have a dictionary, a bool, an int that represents an ID, and a string value for the name.  I'm not sure I see the point in creating a bunch of separate objects that all have the same things inside of them instead of just using one object.

What is considered the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise one for each method containing only the request and response information that that method provides and returns. The reason being that it will be clearer to calling clients what the expectations of that method are when they generate their proxy code from the wsdl.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Nick Ryan's answer. Check out the blog I wrote some time ago for details http://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2012/01/12/pros-and-cons-of-service-layer-designs/

Answer (score 0):

IMO there isn't a one-size-fits all answer - it depends

If you have 'control' over both ends of the wire (i.e. your own .NET client is the only consumer of the WCF services), then shared type makes sense (i.e. reusing the same entity assemblies on client and server). If you do this, then having a common set of entities which is shared across all services in your project would save time reinventing the wheel (e.g. for Result Codes, Pagination Information, additional custom contextual information, etc). You can also either use generated service refernces, or directly use ClientBase<> in your client against shared ServiceContract interfaces. In this case, you don't really 'care' what the data looks like across the wire, as long as it serializes / deserializes correctly.

However, if there are other, non .NET consumers of your WCF serice then there are other considerations.

DataContractSerializer creates a request and response schema for each method (usually Method, and MethodResponse) with the method signature exposed on both (including parameter variable names). It will depend on the client WSDL mapping technology as to whether common entities in the request and response will be 'rolled' into reusable entities, or whether new entities will be created each time.

With DCS there is no 'pressure' to wrap unrelated fields / parameters into a single class - e.g. your message signature can be

```
public DoSomethingResult DoSomething(int parameter1, SomeEntity parameter2, string parameter3);
```

You can also consider [MessageContracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx). This 'forces' you to think a lot more about what the data looks like across the wire, and the requests and responses are contained in wrapper entities. IMO MessageContracts work well in EAI scenarios (e.g. if you have a BizTalk consumer), as a common response message such as you are suggesting can then be reused across multiple service calls.

HTH